# Default generic works as expected as parameter but not as a return type for a function parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have managed to use a default for my generic of type A and this works well when using it as an object parameter (function c), however if I attempt to use it as the return type of a passed in function parameter (function d) it does not correctly error with `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ping' does not exist in type 'B'.`

```
type A = { foo: string }
type B = { bar: string }

function c<T = A, InferredType extends T = T>(config: InferredType): void { }
function d<T = A, InferredType extends T = T>(config: () => InferredType): void { }

c({ foo: 'foo' });
c({ bar: 'bar' }); // Correctly errors
c<A>({ bar: 'bar' }); // Correctly errors
c<B>({ bar: 'bar' });
c<B>({ bar: 'bar', ping: 'ping' }); // Correctly errors

d(() => ({ foo: 'foo' }));
d(() => ({ bar: 'bar' })); // Correctly errors
d<A>(() => ({ bar: 'bar' })); // Correctly errors
d<B>(() => ({ bar: 'bar' }));
d<B>(() => ({ bar: 'bar', ping: 'ping' })); // Should error with unknown property but doesn't
d<B>((): B => ({ bar: 'bar', ping: 'ping' })); // Errors correctly but requires duplicate type
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=95&pln=1&pc=1#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)

If I specify the type (B) a second time, as you can see on the final line, it works as expected but this defeats the purpose of using a generic in the first place.

Is this an issue with typescript itself or am I missing something here?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781523/interface-is-allowing-extra-property-when-it-is-used-as-return-type-of-a-functio) help out?

Comment: It is relatd to how excess property checks work. `d<B>(() => ({ bar: 'bar', ping: 'ping' }))` compiles, as the return type of the inner callback is just expected to be structurally assignable (speak sub-type) to `B` as instantiation of type parameter `InferredType`. The given object literal does not need to match `B` exactly: You did not annotate the inner callback return type explicitely with `B`, so the object type is inferred here in the inner function context.

Comment: Or said differently, in order to let excess property checks work, you have to "immediately" type the object literal in the context - like in the last example, that emits an error.

Comment: Thank you @ford04. That answer did help out. It is a shame that I cannot force this "fresh" check via generics unless I have missed something. My use case is enforcing specific definitions for selector generation in an existing code base. I may have to handle this via tslint ruling. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been looking into your issue and in my understanding, it is supposed to be working like that.

If you look into your `d()` function's type, you have a `InferredType extends T`.

On lines 16-18, `T` is passed as `B`. When you try with `T` being passed as `A` (`d<A>(() => ({ bar: 'bar', ping: 'ping' }));`) it will trigger an error saying that `foo` is required.

So what I think is that your InferredType is interpreted as being `{ ping?: string}` as it extends your `T` type. And you can go on and on with for example: `d<B>(() => ({ bar: 'bar', ping: 'ping', pong: 'pong', hello: 'hello' }));`. As long as `bar` is defined, there is no error.

Don't hesitate to ask if it is not clear enough!