# typescript type check error does not shown when not all property matches

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

If interface A and interface B have just one common property, typescript compiler-error like this is not shown. Why?

```
Type '{ a: string; c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'c' does not exist in type 'A'.
```

This error should be shown not only for **object literal** but also **interface**.

1. Can anyone answer following questions? (Q1, Q2, Q3)
2. Are there any way to check more strict?

```
interface A {
    a?: string;
    b?: number;
}

interface B {
    a?: string;
    c?: number;
}

interface C {
    x?: string;
}

const f = (args: A[]) => {
    console.log(args);
};

// (1) error: type check 
const x = () => {
    f([{ a: 'a', c: 1 }]);
};

// (2) no error. Q1. what is the difference between (1) and (2)?
const y = () => {
    const args = [
        { a: 'a', c: 1 }
    ]
    f(args);
};

// (3) error: A and C have no common property
const z = () => {
    f([] as C[]);
};

// (4) no error. [Q2] what is the difference between (3) and (4)?
const w = () => {
    f([] as B[]);
};

// (5) error: A and C have no common property
const u = () => {
    f([{ x: 1 } as C]);
};

// (6) no error. [Q3] what is the difference between (5) and (6)?
const v = () => {
    f([{ c: 1 } as B]);
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=40&ssc=3&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XAfgC5kBnMKUAcwG4c8AjY5EAVwFsHo6BfLLUJFiIUAIUz1chEuUohak5AmZtO3LHwHho8JMgDCEvMgAezWdV78EAexDlkMZAF5kACjhQqpEqgDaALoAlC4AfBIAkLb2NgA2EAB0sTZUHl6kQbx0WAD0Oe4AjCHQUDZQJGAAngAOKAgAFhAIANbIWNEOJi7uIc7h2MYwbn4Y+CQA5HDjADRKJAXIPMFZ-HnuAEwhIDbIJWUJyACKBQcA7vVwYMjApMhgjcgAJsAwMNAQIHpcYKcQH4UhOAgR4bIIEdp2ByVbpuXr9RQdK6ebzdPyKYyjOATKazBDzRaKAKKIbIjIrXL5NwAZmKUFK5TQ+GBBmQFwAbihtkobOx2HZkNVSrUoFUIfYrgAvGFwox4IaBfC3fSBTIabJrNwAFi2Oz2UAOfkO6wCyHOl2ut3uKGer3enxQ31+-2pgOZWrBYocp2lYVluHlJrgt1EKvJGoArLT6b4mSDDOzOTtbLz+YKbMLRYjkKwfX0-Y5hqMTPieIqDMs1atKQA2HW7On7ZCGqkms1XG53B42t5QD5fCA-P4gdyR2PuWvgrNs3PwwaFubIBaloPIUQVng0IA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface is allowing extra property when it is used as return type of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781523/interface-is-allowing-extra-property-when-it-is-used-as-return-type-of-a-functio)

Comment: thank you. but this is not enough I think. I edited my question to make it easier to understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the difference between (1) and (2)?**

```
// (1) error: type check 
const x = () => {
    f([{ a: 'a', c: 1 }]);
};

// (2) no error. 
const y = () => {
    const args = [
        { a: 'a', c: 1 }
    ]
    f(args);
};
```

In (1), there is an explicit type `A` given for the object literal you create as item of the array parameter in `f`. Hence [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) (a neat safety *feature* for the developer!) kick in, which don't allow additional properties like `c`. ==> error

In (2) the type of `const args` is inferred by the compiler (no explicit type) and there are no excess property checks here. `[{ a: 'a', c: 1 }]` [structurally](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) fits the `f` function parameter `A[]`, because the compiler recognized at least one property `a` from `A` in your given `args`. And property `b` in `A` is optional/can be `undefined` ([TS docs example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) with "common property") ==> compiles

Fix for (2) - Annotate an explicit type:

```
// now errors
const args: A[] = [
        { a: 'a', c: 1 }
]
```

---

**What is the difference between (3) and (4)?**

```
// (3) error: A and C have no common property
const z = () => {
    f([] as C[]);
};

// (4) no error. 
const w = () => {
    f([] as B[]);
};
```

With a type assertion in (3), you say that the compiler shall treat `[]` `as C[]`. `C` is not assignable/no sub-type of `A`, so `C[]` cannot be passed to something that expects `A[]`. `B` is assignable to `A`, so that works! (4).

---

**What is the difference between (5) and (6)?**

```
// (5) error: A and C have no common property
const u = () => {
    f([{ x: 1 } as C]);
};

// (6) no error. 
const v = () => {
    f([{ c: 1 } as B]);
};
```

(5) is like above: `C` doesn't fit `A`. (6) is more interesting: You enforce `{ c: 1 }` to be `B`, which is valid. And this type assertion undermines excess property checks, so the argument just structural fits again.

Given your type assertions in (4) and (6), it is not clear/depends on the context, how we can "make it more strict". Maybe leave out the assertion at all?

Hope, that helps in addition to [mentioned question](http://Interface%20is%20allowing%20extra%20property%20when%20it%20is%20used%20as%20return%20type%20of%20a%20function).

Comment: thank you for your great answer!! `B is assignable to A` is a little strange for me...

Comment: In how far "strange" ? :-) Honestly, my first reaction had been similar ... but it makes sense from a structural typing perspective. As `b` is optional in `A`, we can always use type `B` in place of `A`. The only thing, that can help us in this case , are excess property checks.