# Typescript specify return or type of function is not the same

Tags: typescript

```
const a1: () => { a: string } = () => {
  return {a: '', b: ''} // not erroring!?
}

const a2 = ():{ a: string } => {
  return {a: '', b: ''} // is erroring as expected
}

const a3: () => { a: string } = () => {
  return {b: ''} // is erroring as expected
}
```

playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgRgFwwBQEoYF4B8MDe8K0ATgJZgDmMAvtmprgQFAwwkCmUAriWAXBQByIQBoYAI2FC6AelkwwIWBxIkQ5KgEIA-MxrNmoSLDgAmehiSFBMUhWp0m+Vuy69++WyPFSYIuQUyCBhVdU1qOBCOAA8ABw5gKA4AE31DY2h4AGYUDGw8G2IoCNpLRkLXTh4+Aj8AmHkYYNC1DQd4aPjE5LSaIA

These 2 should be the same thing, but somehow the `a2` has a typescript error.

My code is done in a format for a1 (defined the function) and it's not erroring. I'd like to know what I have to do to error if is incorrect.

As you can see in a3, it's erroring. So it's still checking for the type, but not as accurately as in a2. So weird.

"typescript": "^3.7.2"

[Error in ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF4ap.png)

```
interface State {a:string}
const similarToRealWorldIssue: (state:State ) => State  = (state) => {
  return {...state, b: 'ssda'} // here I meant to put `a`, but I put `b` by mistake and nobody complained.
}
```

Comment: I think in the first case you’re assigning ():{a:string, b:string} to variable of type ():{a:string} which is not wrong but in the second case you’re defining ():{a:string} and then proceed to return {a:string, b:string} which _is_ wrong.

Comment: But look at a3, which is erroring. By your explanation a3 should not error.

Comment: In the third case you’re trying to assign ():{b:string} to variable of type ():{a:string} which is wrong as you cannot extract a:string from {b:string}, but you can extract it from {a:string, b:string}.

Comment: so what is the return type of a1 and a2? If you inspect is exactly the same. But they dont behave the same. I can't see anywhere in the docs that depending on how you define the function will match the return or just include the return. Makes no sense IMO

Comment: a3 is not wrong because it is returning {b:string} but because you’re assigning something that is returning {b:string} to variable that expects something that’s returning {a:string} and there’s no a:string in {b:string}.

Comment: Related but not the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816061/why-am-i-getting-an-error-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface is allowing extra property when it is used as return type of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781523/interface-is-allowing-extra-property-when-it-is-used-as-return-type-of-a-functio)

Comment: In a1 you’re assigning an anonymous function to variable a1, whereas in a2 you’re defining a function in place which is subtly different. The anonymous function you’re assigning to the variable has a different but compatible type to a1 and that is why you don’t get an error there.

Comment: any way to have all errorring on excess properties?

Answer (score 1):

Your `similarToRealWorldIssue` function can be broken down into two parts.

The first part,

```
const similarToRealWorldIssue: (state:State ) => State
```

which declares and specifies that `similarToRealWorldIssue` will have a return type of `State`.

The second part,

```
    = (state) => {
      return {...state, b: 'ssda'}
    }
```

which is a function without an explicitly defined return type, and therefore returns `any`.
The typescript compiler does not complain because the type `any` may as well be `State`.

You can solve this in two ways.

Solution 1: Specify `State` as a return type for the second part of your arrow function.

```
    const similarToRealWorldIssue: (state:State ) => State  = (state): State => {
      return {...state, b: 'ssda'}
    }
```

Solution 2: Preferred solution because it simplifies your function and makes it easier to read.

```
    const similarToRealWorldIssue = (state: State): State => {
      return{
        a: '',
      }
    };
```

In this case, any additional field not required will yield a compiler error likewise omission to required fields.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but I already figured out I can put `State` at the end, but that's not optimal because is not DRY. As I've said I have an interface that must be followed by all these functions and it's error prone to add the return type on each one.

Answer (score 0):

In essence what is happening in the first case is something like this:

```
const a1_anon = () => {
  return {a: '', b: ''} // not erroring!?
}
// inferred type of a1_anon is () => {a: string, b: string}
const a1: () => { a: string } = a1_anon
```

If you want it to not be happening, you need to specify type so it won’t be inferred like this:

```
const a1: () => { a: string } = (): {a: string} => {
  return {a: '', b: ''} // not erroring!?
}
```

I know it’s specified twice but since you’re insisting on defining an anonymous function and then assigning it to the variable, there’s no other way around it.

Of course you can go the way you’re defining `a2` as that is not specifying the type twice and does what you need but you already know that.

For your specific problem, you could just use the `a2` way of defining things. If the `State` interface is not too big then you could always assign all the values to returned `State` object, that way if you mistype something it will be a missing property instead of an additional one (the `...` usage here is problematic in my opinion anyway). Yet another way would be to define a function and use it *always* when returning a `State` object.

```
const statify = (state: State): State => { return state }
const exampleUsage: (state: State) => State = (state) => {
  return statify({...state, c: '' })
}
```

Failing all that you might want to define a `State` class with getter and setter methods and use that instead of an arbitrary object. Also not sure if you want to always copy state and change its properties but if you do, you could implement a method in that class for making a copy.

One more option came to mind, this would change `{...state, <properties>}` into `stateAdd(state, {<properties>})`

```
interface State { a: string, b: string }
interface StateAddition { a?: string, b?: string }
const stateAdd = (state: State, additional: StateAddition): State => {
  return { ...state, ...additional }
}
const exampleUsage: (state: State) => State = (state) => {
  return stateAdd(state, {c: ''})
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have many of these functions that should addere to a proper API, and by doing that is error prone and leads to a lot of duplication which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: They _do_ adhere to the API just have additional properties, that’s fine as far as the interface is concerned. You’ll be able to use those returned objects the way you expect so that makes it fine in the eyes of the compiler.

Comment: yeah, but I just found a bug because I misstyped one key and there was no error. This is for a series of reducers so i need to use `...` spread operator and therefore will add the correct property + the misstyped one.

Comment: Could you share a more relevant code example for the bug you found so that we can try to solve _that_ problem?

Comment: I've added an example `similarToRealWorldIssue`

Comment: the question is how can I ensure all these reducers will call the statify function?

Comment: If you’re not in control of all those reducers and are afraid that they will do something fishy, then the only way to go is to make a class for state and restrict what they can do with that class via its interface.