# Typescript Record<number, string> accepts number on Key

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm new to typescript and there's still a lot to study but I've stumble with this [code](https://blog.logrocket.com/async-await-in-typescript) that is quite confusing for me about the Record utility types.

This code works on the playground

```js
const data = async (name: string, id: number): Promise<Record<number,string>> => {
  const obj = {
    foo: 'bar', //shouldn't this not work since I've used 'number'?
  }
  return obj
}
```

This one does not (2nd line)

```
const foo1: Record<string, string> = { foo: 'bar' }
const foo2: Record<number, string> = { foo: 'bar' }
```

Why is this? I am also not sure what kind of data type should be used in the 'key'. Try typescript playground

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface is allowing extra property when it is used as return type of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781523/interface-is-allowing-extra-property-when-it-is-used-as-return-type-of-a-functio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because TS should be compatible with JavaScript.

Consider this pure js code:

```js
const foo={
  0:42
}

const x = foo['0'] // number
const y = foo[0] // number
```

As you might have noticed, JS allows you to use both string and number key for `0: 42`

See both js and ts docs:

[js explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#property_names)

> Property names
> Property names are string or Symbol. Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string. This outputs 'value', since 1 is coerced into '1'.

[ts explanation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

> It is possible to support both types of indexers, but the type returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned from the string indexer. This is because when indexing with a `number`, JavaScript will actually convert that to a `string` before indexing into an object. That means that indexing with `100` (a `number`) is the same thing as indexing with `"100"` (a `string`), so the two need to be consistent.

*Why is this? I am also not sure what kind of data type should be used in the 'key'.*

TypeScript has built in type for key: `type PropertyKey = string | number | symbol`

You can use `PropertyKey` without declaration. This type is built in